Nginx can't serve Django url over Gunicorn Docker container
I am trying to deploy my Django Docker application with Nginx and Gunicorn.I followed this tutorial.I also managed to run my Django app on :8000 and Nginx on :80, I can reach both :80 and :8000 but when I try to connect to for example :80/app I just get a 404, at the same time I can connect to :8000/app.
My main Docker File looks like:
FROM python:3.10.6-alpine

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirments.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirments.txt

COPY ./proto /app
WORKDIR /app 

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/entrypoint.sh" ]

this run my entrypoint.sh:
python manage.py migrate --no-input
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

gunicorn proto.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`

and my compose.yml looks like:

version: '3.7'

services:
  django_proto:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_proto

volumes:
  static:


and my default.conf:
upstream django {
    server django_proto:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://django;

        proxy_redirect off;
    }      
}

and the Nginx Docker File:
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

[EDIT: I looked at the default.conf file on the running server with Dokcer Desktop and it's my modified version of the default.conf.]
I tried different folder constructs because I thought I was just trying to connect to the wrong folder path, I also tried different ports and even closed my firewall in case it was blocking the connection.

Could you add the Dockerfile that lives in ./nginx? Obviously your gunicorn app is running fine, but your nginx is not working as it should. I assume that the started nginx process does not use the config that you showed above.

i agree with @Tarquinius
you should try
run
chown nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && 
chown nginx:nginx /var/log/nginx/error.log && \

proxy_pass has have the right hostname and include the port.

@Domenic: Just checking if your config is within the container is not enough. Please opt into the nginx container and run nginx -t. That should test and check the currently used config. Next step then would be to look into the access.log and error.log files of nginx. You'll also find them inside of the container. It should give more info about why it gives the 404.
